# What does the minus sign mean in a `movl` instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I have this assembly code:

```
movl -4(%ebp),%eax
```

What does the `-4` before the `(%ebp)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -4 is a constant offset to the pointer held by the register. This code reads the long value at `ebp - 4` and stores it in `eax`. This is AT&T syntax; the Intel syntax for the same instruction would be `mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-4]`.